# Using symbols in <pre> tag

Tags: html, symbols, pre

Normally to print symbols such as the forall symbol, you'd just use &forall, but this doesn't seem to work in pre blocks that literally print out "&forall".

```
<pre>
&forall o in orders
</pre>
```

What would be a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all browsers have the bug/feature that many entity references are not recognized without a trailing semicolon, even in contexts where it is valid to omit the semicolon. As others have suggested, using `&forall;` circumvents the bug. The HTML 4.01 spec indirectly refers to the bug when it [recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3) the use of trailing semicolons for all entity references.

Another solution is to use the FOR ALL character “∀” itself, provided that your document is UTF-8 encoded and declared as such. This makes the source code more readable.

This does not depend on the use of `pre` markup. The issue is the same e.g. in text directly inside the `body` element.

Note that `pre` elements are by default rendered using a monospace font. This is unsuitable for mathematical expressions (they should normally be displayed using a serif font), and the browser’s default monospace font might lack the “∀” character or other mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine in a `pre` tag, you just forgot the semicolon at the end of the entity:

```
<pre>
&forall; o in orders
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is not just `&forall`. A semicolon is required.

Like: `&forall;`

Answer (score 2):

you're missing semicolon

```
<pre>
&forall; o in orders
</pre>
```

```
∀ o in orders
```